# Speed up cracking a wpa2.hccapx file in hashcat

Tags: passwords, password-cracking, wpa2, hashcat

I'm trying to do a brute force with Hashcat on windows with a GPU cracking a wpa2.hccapx handshake. Based on my research I know the password is **10 characters**, **a mix of random lowercase + numbers only**

Hashcat says it will take 10 years using `?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a?a` AND it will take almost 115 days to crack it when I use `?h?h?h?h?h?h?h?h?h?h`.

Is there any way to minimize this?

I was reading in several places that if I use certain commands it will help to speed the process but I don't feel like I'm doing it correctly.

Comment: What kind of hardware do you have?

Comment: AMD Ramdeon RTX 580 8gb, I even tried the Super Powerful Cloud Hashing Server with 8 GPU's and still gives me 12 yrs to decrypted the wpa2.hccax file, I want to think that something is wrong on my command line. 

I used, 
hashcat.exe -a 3 -m 2500 -d 1 wpa2.hccapx -increment (password 10 characters long) -1 ?l?d (**?L(lowercase)?D**)  ?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1

Answer (score 1):

It will take about 600 years to brute force through all of your combinations (`<Number of characters>^<Password length>/<Hashes per second>/60/60/24/365`).
I will still give you the instructions since knowing them might be useful for other cases.

The first step is to define your specific charset.
Hashcat provides the following built-in charsets:

```
  ? | Charset
 ===+=========
  l | abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz [a-z]
  u | ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ [A-Z]
  d | 0123456789                 [0-9]
  h | 0123456789abcdef           [0-9a-f]
  H | 0123456789ABCDEF           [0-9A-F]
  s |  !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
  a | ?l?u?d?s
  b | 0x00 - 0xff
```

Since your password is 10 chars and of mixed random lowercase + numbers only, you need to define a custom charset with the flag `-1 ?d?l`. By doing so, you define the charset `?1` that contains all lowercase letters (`?l`) and all numbers (`?d`). Then you need to use `?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1` as the mask, since your password is exactly 10 characters long.

Now to the ways of improving your cracking speed.

1. Hashcat `-m2500` is deprecated. Convert your cap file to the pmkid hash format for best performance. This can easily be done using `hcxpcapngtool -o <output file> <.cap file>`.
2. Use all of your available processors. `hashcat -I` shows all of your available GPUs and CPUs. Use the flags `-D` or `-d` to make use all of your devices. (Keep in mind that CPU cracking is under normal circumstances much slower than GPU cracking)
3. Use the `-w` flag

```
- [ Workload Profiles ] -

  # | Performance | Runtime | Power Consumption | Desktop Impact
 ===+=============+=========+===================+=================
  1 | Low         |   2 ms  | Low               | Minimal
  2 | Default     |  12 ms  | Economic          | Noticeable
  3 | High        |  96 ms  | High              | Unresponsive
  4 | Nightmare   | 480 ms  | Insane            | Headless
```

With `-w` you can specify how much of the available computing resources will be utilized by hashcat. Use `-w 4` for best performance.

4. Use `--markov-disable` to disable markov chains (password guesses based on statistical patterns). Markov chains can drastically decrease cracking time when attempting to crack a password that isn't randomly generated. Since your searched password is completely random, we can disable it to save a little computing power.